# Access File and Database on Desktop from Windows Phone

Tags: sql-server, authentication, windows-mobile, filesystems, windows-phone

I am currently working on a windows phone 6.0 application. This application accesses the files and database on my desktop.

1. Now I can get this app connect the database sql-server 2005 via user/password authentication, but cannot via windows integral authentication. Is there any trick here?
2. I cannot get access to the file on my desktop. Always got the exception "[System.ArgumentException] = {"Value does not fall within the expected range."}" Should I configure something to make the windows phone to visit the file system on my desktop not on the phone?

Can anyone shed some light on this? Thanks.

Comment: You should clarify this question. Are you talking about Windows Mobile 6.0 or Windows Phone 7? Two different operating systems.

Answer (score 2):

What is the connections string you are currently using?

It should look similar to this:

```
"Server={YourServer};Initial Catalog={YourDatabase};Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID={YourLogin};Password={YourPassword};"
```

You still have to supply a user id and password because the device has no knowledge of a user that is currently logged into it.  Also make sure to add a domain to the user id if needed.